# Can i get condition if the conversion is success?

Tags: vb.net

This is the example :

`Dim a As String = "2018-08-08"`

`Dim b As Date`

Can i do this in vb.net ? This is the algorithm :

```
If (b=a) is success Then
.........
End If
```

I hope you know what i mean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's what the `TryParse` and `TryParseExact` methods of the `DateTime` type are for.  They will attempt to convert a `String` to a `DateTime` and return a `Boolean` that indicates whether it was successful or not.  If it is successful, the `DateTime` is output via a parameter declared `ByRef`, e.g.

```
If Date.TryParse(a, b) Then
    'The conversion was successful and 'a' contains the Date value.
Else
    'The conversion failed and 'a' contains the default value for a Date.
End If
```

Comment: I would recommended [**TryParseExact**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

Comment: As @Çöđěxěŕ suggests, you should generally use `TryParseExact` if you expect one or more specific formats and don't want to accept any others.  `TryParse` will work for various formats but relies on the specific regional settings of the local machine.